# Use FileUtil.copyMerge on Google Dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to merge multiple files generated by a Spark job into one file. Usually I'd do something like:

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
val deleteSrcFiles = true
FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), deleteSrcFiles, hadoopConfig, null)
```

This runs fine locally, using paths e.g /tmp/some/path/to.csv, but results in an Exception when executed on a cluster my-cluster:

`Wrong FS: gs://myBucket/path/to/result.csv, expected: hdfs://my-cluster-m`

Is this possible to get a FileSystem for gs:// paths from scala/java code running on a Dataproc cluster?

---

### EDIT

Found the google-storage client library: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use Path's belonging to a particular filesystem with that filesystem e.g. you cannot pass a gs:// path to HDFS as you did above.

The following snippet works for me:

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val srcPath = new Path("hdfs:/tmp/foo")
val hdfs = srcPath.getFileSystem(hadoopConfig)
val dstPath = new Path("gs://bucket/foo")
val gcs = dstPath.getFileSystem(hadoopConfig)
val deleteSrcFiles = true
FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, srcPath, gcs, dstPath, deleteSrcFiles, hadoopConfig, null)
```

Comment: As an aside, FileUtil.copyMerge has been removed in Hadoop 2.8+, consider migrating to another method of merging files (or lift the implementation from Hadoop 2.7). See HADOOP-11661 for details.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java - there are client libraries for google storage.